# view.setColumnHidden (0, True) is not working

Tags: python, pyqt5, qtableview

I have this coding which is working fine. Except some tableview function don't

```
    try:
        model = QtGui.QStandardItemModel()
        view = QtWidgets.QTableView() 
        view.horizontalHeader().hide()
        view.verticalHeader().hide()
        view.setSelectionBehavior(1)
        view.setColumnHidden(0, True)            
        self.comboBox_2.setView(view)
        self.comboBox_2.setModel(model)
        data = helper.select("Select fahrerid, fahrervorname || fahrernachname from fahrer")            
        for row in data:
            items = []
            for item in row:
                items.append(QtGui.QStandardItem(str(item)))
            model.appendRow(items)
    except Exception as e:
        ErrorLogger.WriteError('Line 177: ' + str(e))
        QtWidgets.QMessageBox.critical(None, 'Exception raised', format(e))
```

Only this is not working:

view.setColumnHidden (0, True)

Same with hide a column

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The visibility of rows and columns can only be set when those rows and columns exist. Since that function is being called *before* setting the model (so there is no row/column count), that call is ignored.

Move that line *after* setting the model on the view.